# Get Ephemeral IP for GCE Instance from NodeJS (or Cloud Function)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-nodejs-client

I am having trouble finding NodeJS API access to either:

1. a list of currently allocated ephemeral IPs and associated instance names, or
2. the ephemeral IP of an instance if I already know its name.

I'm running a cloud function that needs to be able check when a set of ephemeral IP addresses changes for a given base instance name.

The instances are created by an instance group.

I have no problem getting information about instances being inserted/deleted in my function, but I cannot find any way to retrieve the external IP associated with the instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [GCE API doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get#examples) with code examples in various languages. [Google API NodeJS Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/apis/compute) is available at github.

To access the ephemeral IP, it is contained in networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP of the JSON returned from the "Instances: get" function call.

There is another node module referenced in this [alternative documentation](http://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.9.x) which can also cause some confusion.

Comment: Additionally, to access the ephemeral IP, it is contained in networkInterfaces.accessConfigs.natIP of the JSON returned from the function call.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/apis/compute